# Uncaught ReferenceError: Link is not defined React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am using react 0.14.7 with webpack 1.12.13 and I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Link is not defined
```

This error is happening in the browser and everything compiles without error.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router'

export default React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <Link {...this.props} activeClassName="active"/>
  }
})
```

**webpack.config**

```
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/client/js/index.js',

  output: {
    path: 'public',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },

  plugins: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
  ] : [],

  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react' },
      { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']}
    ]
  },

}
```

A little more, to add to the confusion I have consoled `react-router` and there is nothing there:

```
import router from 'react-router'
console.info(router); //undefined
```

Comment: Hmm. What does your webpack config look like? Have you checked the bundled output to see if react-router is getting included?

Comment: Which version of react-router are you using? Could you set up a standalone project somewhere to study?

Comment: ^2.0.0 for react-router, Good thinking I will try and create a new project with the same setup and see if I can get Link to work. I just don't understand why its not there.

Comment: I have the same problem....any solution?

Comment: I'm on v4.0.0-alpha.6, and I had this issue too, but once I required `import { Link } from 'react-router'` all worked. But that's not v.2.

Answer (score 3):

Use `react-router-dom` instead.

`import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
...`

See [react-router-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom) on npm.